# PDEs Lagrange characteristic method for $u_x + 3u_y = 5z + \tan(y-3x)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

Solve the following linear first order PDEs Lagrange characteristic method

$u_x + 3u_y = 5z + \tan(y-3x)$

well then from the Lagrange characteristic equations

$$\frac{dx}{1} = \frac{dy}{3} = \frac{dz}{5z + \tan(y-3x)}$$

The first part is easy from

$\frac{dx}{1} = \frac{dy}{3}$

you obtain
$\psi(x,y,z) = 3x - y = c_2$

The difficult part is obtaining

$\phi(x,y,z) = ?? = c_1$

so as to obtain the general solution that is

$F(\phi(x,y,z) , \psi(x,y,z)) = 0$

any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$u_x + 3u_y +0\:u_z = 5z+\tan(y-3x)$$

Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs :

$$\frac{dx}{1} = \frac{dy}{3}= \frac{dz}{0} = \frac{du}{5z+\tan(y-3x)}$$
A first obvious characteristic equation comes from $dz=0$
$$z=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{1} = \frac{dy}{3}$ :
$$y-3x=c_2$$
A third characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{1} = \frac{du}{5z+\tan(y-3x)}= \frac{du}{5c_1+\tan(c_2))}$ :
$$u-x\:\big(5c_1+\tan(c_2)\big)=c_3$$
The general solution of the PDE on implicit form $c_3=F(c_1,c_2)$ leads to the explicit general solution :
$$u(x,y,z)=x\: \big(5z+\tan(y-3x)\big)+F\big(z \:,\: y-3x \big)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function of two variables. If some valid boundary conditions are specified, one have to determine the function $F$ according to the boundary conditions.